# Enums extend or use traits (reusability)

Tags: php, laravel, enums, php-8.1

I have enums that must have additional methods for translation purposes:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Enums;

enum GenderEnum: string
{
    case MALE = 'male';
    case FEMALE = 'female';

    public function trans(): string
    {
        return trans('enums.' . $this->value);
    }
}
```

This method is trans and it will be duplicated in all enums, how can I avoid duplication? I can't extend it using traits in enums.

Comment: Enums can not be extended, but can use Traits. Why you can't use Traits?

Comment: Yes, You're right, got some strange warning from IDEA, and thought it was about limitations like extends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enum [cannot be extended, and must not inherit](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/enums#enum-inheritance)

but you can use [Traits](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/enums#enum-traits), as long as the trait does not declare any properties

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this one? I even don't want to include traits in every Enum maybe there is some kind of BaseTrait approach?

Comment: @RomkaLTU What's the difference then between writing `extends BaseEnum` vs `use BaseTrait` everywhere?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, Traits should do the job I want, besides not every Enum will be translatable.

Comment: Although, if you need properties for some reason, https://github.com/henzeb/enumhancer  is allowing you to (without breaking the rules). Traits are indeed the way to go, I use them in combination with static class helpers.